# Frequent business travel to Schengen region - which visa do I go for?

Tags: visas, schengen

Because of the business requirements, I will have to visit the Schengen countries on a frequent basis for short time spans. The main reason of visit is travel and most of my trips will be to Germany and France, but this can change from visit to visit.

As per what I can see on the VFS Germany website for India, they only give a national visa to the following categories -

> Work Permit, Student, German Classes, Family Reunion, Au Pair, Specialty Cook, Medical Treatment, Guest Scientist and Visiting Scholars.

I need to visit my clients and won't have a work permit. I have got Schengen visas multiple times previously, but for tourism. From which country do I apply for such a visa which will be valid for at least 2-3 years? Will there be a problem in case a year or so down the line I enter a country for business, for example Latvia, on this visa?

Comment: 3.  [National Visas](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-types/)
 _On the other hand a multi-entry national visa is also granted for certain individuals, allowing its holder **to travel in and out of this Schengen country as he/she pleases** and also travel throughout the whole Schengen Area without additional visa requirements_.

Comment: @SheikPaul national visas are for stays of longer than 90 days. Such a visa is not indicated here. Instead, a multiple-entry uniform short-stay visa would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

A national D visa would by required if you want to visit a Schengen state for *more than 90 days out of any 180 days*. For frequent short trips, the best would be a Schengen C visa with multiple entries and a very long duration.

Long, multiple-entry visa are given if there is a premise to justify them and if the applicant had shorter, possibly single-entry visa before without any problems.

Even if the duration was more than a year, the multi-entry visa would still be subject to the 90/180 rule, it just saves you the hassle of repeated applications. Is is possible to visit many different Schengen states with such a multiple-entry visa as long as it says "Schengen states" or the equivalent in the respective language. The premise for the *initial* trip needs to be documented in detail with the application. For later trips you should keep the medical insurance in mind, bring enough money to cover your cost of living, have a plan for onward travel, etc.